# Any performance difference on this variation of join on 2 tables?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Let us assume we have 2 tables - EMP & DEPT.
EMP can be joined with DEPT on department_id column (contained by both tables)

Let us assume the EMP table has 1000 employees. Out of those , 100 of them have salaries less than 1000. Let us assume there is no index on any column.

I can write a query to fetch the employees in three different ways. Is there any option which gives me performance benefit-

## 1

```
select * from emp i, dept h
where i.department_id = h.department_id
and i.salary <1000;
```

## 2

```
select * from emp i join dept h
on i.department_id = h.department_id
and i.salary <1000;
```

## 3

```
select * from emp i join dept h
on i.department_id = h.department_id
where i.salary <1000;
```

I tried the explain plan for the 3 queries and all were identical. Logically speaking, I think that all should give same performance.

Comment: what is the diff btween 2 and 3 ?

Comment: In 2, there is 'and'. In 3, there is 'where'. I don't know any logical difference.

Comment: So the conclusion is? My advice is to always use new style, explicit JOIN syntax. Easier to write, easier to read, and much easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: 1 is the query I use and have seen used.

Comment: I'd say go with query 3. Query 1 is using older, implicit join syntax. (My comment above describes why you should do explicit joins instead.)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to settle this question is to call `EXPLAIN PLAN` and take a look at the execution plans. On my server, they all look the same. So now the difference boils down to styles.

Don't use #1. It is the old join syntax that I first cut my teeth with all the way back in SQL Server 7.0 in 1999. It's not immediately apparent what the relationship between these 2 tables is. Things get hairier the more tables participate in the join.

#2 and #3 is a wash. I've seen an equal number of developers choosing each style. Pick one and stay with it.